# Adding Razor to mature, existing Servicestack project without changing existing functionality

Tags: razor, servicestack

I have a years-old ServiceStack project that provides services to both legacy Winforms apps as well as newer html/css/javascript webs. I now have the need to serve some pre-formatted views to some of these apps (especially as we add a Xamarin mobile platform), and it seems like Servicestack.Razor would be the logical way to go.

I'm not sure the best way to add Razor to an existing project as opposed to starting over with a new project. Can I add the necessary view folders, references and web.config elements myself?

Also, what is the standard URL convention for still having the service be available (callable from the above apps), but now adding view(s) of that service? Is this a new route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Razor to an existing ServiceStack Web App by adding the required [config sections to your Web.config](http://docs.servicestack.net/razor-notes#web-configuration-for-razor):

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false"/>
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System" />
                <add namespace="System.Linq" />
                <add namespace="ServiceStack" />
                <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
                <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
                <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
                <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
                <add namespace="ProjectNamespace" />
                <add namespace="ProjectNamespace.ServiceModel" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

Then Installing the ServiceStack.Razor package:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Razor
```

Which will configure your project to enable [ServiceStack's Razor support](http://razor.servicestack.net/). From there you can add a view for your Service by naming it after your Request or Response DTO, e.g:

```
/Views
    RequestDto.cshtml
    /Shared
        _Layout.cshtml
```

As it's a view model for your existing Service, the `@model` will be for your Services Response DTO.

If everything's configured correctly, calling your existing Service from a browser (or any HTTP Request with `Accept: text/html`) will return the output from your view instead of ServiceStack's [built-in auto HTML output](http://docs.servicestack.net/html5reportformat).